# Cassandra's medusa backup not working. Backup job created, but status missing and medusa container logs not updated(stuck)

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, medusa, k8ssandra

I am trying to create medusa backup by running below command, but it doesn't work, it only creates the medusabackup job in MedusaBackupJobs folder, but I never get the status in the medusabackup job and also the backup is not completed. The job is stuck.

I checked the medusa container log and couldn't find any logs for the backup job snapshot creation or upload, the only logs that I could see in the medusa is pasted below => "starting server. Listening on port 50051." Running of below command doesn't generate any additional logs.

**kubectl apply -n k8ssandra-operator -f 'medusa-backup-full.yaml'**

**medusa-backup-full.yaml**

```
apiVersion: medusa.k8ssandra.io/v1alpha1 
kind: MedusaBackupJob 
metadata: name: backup-1 
spec: cassandraDatacenter: dc1 
backupType: full
```

**medusa config in k8ssandra deployment yaml file**

```
medusa: 
containerImage: registry: xx.yy.zz.cloud/docker-repositories 
tag: 0.13.4 
storageProperties: 
bucketName: cass-backups 
concurrentTransfers: 1 
host: minio.xxx.cloud 
port: 443 
maxBackupAge: 1 
maxBackupCount: 2 
multiPartUploadThreshold: 10000000000000000 
prefix: dc1 
storageProvider: s3_compatible 
storageSecretRef: name: cass-backups
```

Medusa container Logs

```
MEDUSA_MODE = GRPC
sleeping for 0 sec
Starting Medusa gRPC service
WARNING:root:The CQL_USERNAME environment variable is deprecated and has been replaced by the MEDUSA_CQL_USERNAME variable
WARNING:root:The CQL_PASSWORD environment variable is deprecated and has been replaced by the MEDUSA_CQL_PASSWORD variable
WARNING:root:The CQL_USERNAME environment variable is deprecated and has been replaced by the MEDUSA_CQL_USERNAME variable
WARNING:root:The CQL_PASSWORD environment variable is deprecated and has been replaced by the MEDUSA_CQL_PASSWORD variable
INFO:root:Init service
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,039] INFO: Init service
DEBUG:root:Loading storage_provider: s3_compatible
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,040] DEBUG: Loading storage_provider: s3_compatible
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Changing event name from creating-client-class.iot-data to creating-client-class.iot-data-plane
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,040] DEBUG: Changing event name from creating-client-class.iot-data to creating-client-class.iot-data-plane
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Changing event name from before-call.apigateway to before-call.api-gateway
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,041] DEBUG: Changing event name from before-call.apigateway to before-call.api-gateway
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Changing event name from request-created.machinelearning.Predict to request-created.machine-learning.Predict
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,042] DEBUG: Changing event name from request-created.machinelearning.Predict to request-created.machine-learning.Predict
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Changing event name from before-parameter-build.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration to before-parameter-build.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,043] DEBUG: Changing event name from before-parameter-build.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration to before-parameter-build.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Changing event name from before-parameter-build.route53 to before-parameter-build.route-53
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,043] DEBUG: Changing event name from before-parameter-build.route53 to before-parameter-build.route-53
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Changing event name from request-created.cloudsearchdomain.Search to request-created.cloudsearch-domain.Search
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,043] DEBUG: Changing event name from request-created.cloudsearchdomain.Search to request-created.cloudsearch-domain.Search
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Changing event name from docs.*.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section to docs.*.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,044] DEBUG: Changing event name from docs.*.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section to docs.*.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Changing event name from before-parameter-build.logs.CreateExportTask to before-parameter-build.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,045] DEBUG: Changing event name from before-parameter-build.logs.CreateExportTask to before-parameter-build.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Changing event name from docs.*.logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section to docs.*.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,046] DEBUG: Changing event name from docs.*.logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section to docs.*.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Changing event name from before-parameter-build.cloudsearchdomain.Search to before-parameter-build.cloudsearch-domain.Search
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,046] DEBUG: Changing event name from before-parameter-build.cloudsearchdomain.Search to before-parameter-build.cloudsearch-domain.Search
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Changing event name from docs.*.cloudsearchdomain.Search.complete-section to docs.*.cloudsearch-domain.Search.complete-section
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,046] DEBUG: Changing event name from docs.*.cloudsearchdomain.Search.complete-section to docs.*.cloudsearch-domain.Search.complete-section
DEBUG:root:Setting AWS credentials file to /etc/medusa-secrets/credentials
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,046] DEBUG: Setting AWS credentials file to /etc/medusa-secrets/credentials
DEBUG:botocore.session:Setting config variable for credentials_file to '/etc/medusa-secrets/credentials'
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,046] DEBUG: Setting config variable for credentials_file to '/etc/medusa-secrets/credentials'
DEBUG:botocore.utils:IMDS ENDPOINT: http://169.254.xxx.xxx/
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,054] DEBUG: IMDS ENDPOINT: http://169.254.xxx.xxx/
DEBUG:botocore.credentials:Looking for credentials via: env
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,056] DEBUG: Looking for credentials via: env
DEBUG:botocore.credentials:Looking for credentials via: assume-role
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,057] DEBUG: Looking for credentials via: assume-role
DEBUG:botocore.credentials:Looking for credentials via: assume-role-with-web-identity
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,057] DEBUG: Looking for credentials via: assume-role-with-web-identity
DEBUG:botocore.credentials:Looking for credentials via: sso
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,057] DEBUG: Looking for credentials via: sso
DEBUG:botocore.credentials:Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,057] DEBUG: Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
INFO:botocore.credentials:Found credentials in shared credentials file: /etc/medusa-secrets/credentials
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,058] INFO: Found credentials in shared credentials file: /etc/medusa-secrets/credentials
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): minio-yy.xxx.cloud:443
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,061] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): minio-yy.xxx.cloud:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://minio-yy.xxx.cloud:443 "HEAD /di-cassandra-backups HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,092] DEBUG: https://minio-yy.xxx.cloud:443 "HEAD /di-cassandra-backups HTTP/1.1" 200 0
INFO:root:Starting server. Listening on port 50051.
[2023-10-13 00:34:22,094] INFO: Starting server. Listening on port 50051.
```

Can I check anything else to debug this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please any one help